# laurent series expansion ${z+2\over z-1}$ on two annuli

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

i am trying to find the laurent series expansion for

$$f(z)={z+2\over z-1}$$

on both $0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$.
For $0<|z|<1$, my thought has been to rewrite ${z+2\over z-1}$ as ${3\over z-1}+1$, then note

$${3\over z-1}={-3\over 1-z}= -3(1+z+z^2+\ldots).$$

Adding $1$ I get the series $-2-3z-3z^2-\ldots -3z^n$. The wolfram solution suggests there should be some negative powers of $z$. Any help as to where I have gone wrong would be great!

Comment: Well, first of all, your series needs to be infinite for the first bit. There are no poles on $|z|<1$, so if Wolfram is giving you negative powers on that disc, it's wrong.

Comment: [In fact...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%28z%2B2%29%2F%28z-1%29)

Answer (score 1):

So, your approach to $|z|<1$ is correct. As for $|z|>1$ notice that $\frac{1}{|z|}<1$.Then

$\frac{z+2}{z-1} = \frac{z}{z-1} + \frac{2}{z-1} = \frac{1}{1-1/z}+ \frac{1}{z}\frac{2}{1-1/z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{z^{n}}} + \frac{2}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{z^{n}}} = 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{z^{n}}} $

And then it follows the Laurent series.